# Clojure database settings per environment

Tags: clojure

I am using monger to fetch and save some data in MongoDb from my Clojure simple app. I have strong Ruby on Rails background so I am familiar with database settings per environment (development, test, production). I want to have something similar in Clojure. How can I add the environment to my code? I want to do it in Clojure-way, code as data, without any yaml files. I am using Leiningen if it changes something.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Leiningen [profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) feature.

In your project.clj define your profiles (most cases you need dev and prod)

```
:profiles {:dev {:resource-paths ["resource-dev"]}
           :prod {:resource-paths ["resource-prod"]}}
```

Now create 2 directories `resource-dev` and `resource-prod` and create config.clj file in both of them which will have define a map to store configuration. Something like:

```
(ns myapp.config)
(def config {:database "dev"})
```

Then in your app code you can use below snippet to load the config file (only once) and access the config map:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(def config (delay (load-file (.getFile (resource "config.clj")))))
(defn get-config []
  @(force config))
```

Now you can use `get-config` function to access the config map.

Comment: How does the app know which environment is running to load the correct settings?

Comment: You run the app with a specific profile : `lein with-profile dev run`

Comment: And when you deploy to somewhere like Heroku and you can't use lein with-profile (I think, but I have 5 days of after hours Clojure under my belt...). Also, can you set defaults such as run uses "dev" and your tests use "test" unless specified elsewhere?

Comment: John Doe - You can use Heroku and `lein with-profile` via your Procfile, e.g. `web: lein with-profile production trampoline run -m horus.core`

Comment: I'm a little new to clojure, but the above didn't work until I removed the @. What exactly was that deref-future (?) supposed to do there?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [clj-boilerplate](https://github.com/leonardoborges/clj-boilerplate), a sample web app I created.

There's info in the [README](https://github.com/leonardoborges/clj-boilerplate/blob/master/README.markdown) about how it understands environments out of the box and an example environment file can be seen [here](https://github.com/leonardoborges/clj-boilerplate/blob/master/src/clj_boilerplate/env.clj) - but it looks something like this:

```
(def config
  (let [env (or (System/getenv "ENVIRONMENT") "development")]
    ((keyword env)
      {:development
         {:database-url "postgres://lborges:@localhost/clj-boilerplate"}
       :test
         {:database-url "postgres://lborges:@localhost/clj-boilerplate-test"
       :production
         {:database-url (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")}})))
```

I have since evolved this approach but this should get you started.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using Confijulate (plug for a personal project!):

https://github.com/bbbates/confijulate

It allows you to define environment specific configuration maps, and specify which one to use via JVM system properties.